# MATLAB K-means accuracy measurement

Tags: matlab, data-mining, k-means

I am implementing K-means algorithm in Matlab on a 245057x4 matrix dataset with k=2,4,6,... Now, I want to measure the accuracy of the result after every iteration using Davies–Bouldin index or Rand index. How can I achieve this in Matlab? In other words, how can I get a piece of code executed after finishing each iteration? I guess I have to implement the algorithm by myself instead of using the built-in k-means function provided with Matlab Statistics Toolbox?

Also, how can I see the initial centroids chosen by the built-in k-means function?

Thanks a lot,

UPDATED:
I had to make some modifications to the kmeans.m source code to get what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the internal k-means function.

Just do **one iteration only**, then your stuff  then snother iteration. Easy.